# Xpath expression for filtering and selecting an item

Tags: xml, xpath, filtering

I want to filter an array and if there are many results select the first in the array.

```
/Lokation[LokationsArt_Id = '15' or LokationsArt_Id = '25']/../Lokation[1]/Lokation_ID
```

It is possible that there are more than one with id 15 or 25. i only need one of them.
Is there an answer for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**You could simple use:**

```
(/Lokation[LokationsArt_Id = '15' or LokationsArt_Id = '25']//Lokation[1]/Lokation_ID)[1]
```

**BTW, if `LokationsArt_Id` is an `attribute` then you must use:**

```
(/Lokation[@LokationsArt_Id = '15' or @LokationsArt_Id = '25']//Lokation[1]/Lokation_ID)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
/Lokation[LokationsArt_Id = '15' or LokationsArt_Id = '25'][1]/Lokation_ID
```

your code selected the relevant locations, the went up to the parent of these selected locations and selected the first location child of this parent. Sounds like the kind of journey only a satnav could invent.